# Replace TextBox with int

Tags: c#, string, textbox, int

I have the following, and it works:

My player class:

```
    public Player(string Str, string SP)
    {
        Strength = Str;
        StatPoints = SP;
    }
    public string StatPoints
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Strength
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Now on my form1 I have a textbox, and a button. The button increments the value in the textbox by one so long as there is a value above 0 in the SP textbox. Problem is, I am declaring six variables in order to manage two values because I have to convert strings to ints and all that crap. Is there a way to replace text boxes with something that is inherently int? Here is my character sheet code so far.

```
    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Player PCStats = new Player(StrBox.Text, SPBox.Text);
        int IntPCSP = Convert.ToInt16(PCStats.StatPoints);
        int IntPCStr = Convert.ToInt16(PCStats.Strength);

        if (IntPCSP >= 1 && IntPCStr <= 7)
        {
            IntPCStr++;
            IntPCSP--;
            PCStats.Strength = IntPCStr.ToString();
            PCStats.StatPoints = IntPCSP.ToString();
            StrBox.Text = PCStats.Strength;
            SPBox.Text = PCStats.StatPoints;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Earn more experience!");
        }
        /*
        MessageBox.Show("PCStats.StatPoints equals" + PCStats.StatPoints);
        MessageBox.Show("PCStats,Strength equals" + PCStats.Strength);
        MessageBox.Show("IntPCSP Equals" + IntPCSP.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("IntPCStr Equals" + IntPCStr.ToString());
        */
    }
```

Or is there an even easier way to do this I completely overlooked. I was super excited to finally get this bit to work after a lot of trial and error, but I am open to redoing it. I would rather however just replace the text boxes so I am not converting variables all over the place.

Comment: If you are doing WinForms then there is a [NumericUpDown control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) which might be useful for you

Comment: Tried that but I still have to change the value from decimal to int. Also there is the whole issue of up down arrows, but mostly the decimal thing.

Comment: Why not use int when you creat class Player directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quick go, not at a computer with Visual Studio on it but should give you a start. Also, try naming your variables etc to have a bit more meaning. Also, this is to fix what you has **as-is** but see my update / suggestion further down about moving logic into the `Player` class...

**My player class:**

```
public Player(int strength, int statPoints)
{
    this.Strength = strength;
    this.StatPoints = statPoints;
}

public int StatPoints { get; set; }

public int Strength { get; set; }
```

**My Form:**

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Player thePlayer = new Player(int.Parse(StrBox.Text), int.Parse(SPBox.Text));

    if (thePlayer.StatPoints > 0 && thePlayer.Strength < 8)
    {
        thePlayer.Strength++;
        thePlayer.StatPoints--;
        StrBox.Text = thePlayer.Strength.ToString();
        SPBox.Text = thePlayer.StatPoints.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Earn more experience!");
    }
}
```

Obviously you would need to check that the values in the text box were integers. You could use another control, mask the text box etc or on the code replace `int.Parse` with `int.TryParse` which checks it is possible before conversion. Just a few ideas to get you going!

**- UPDATE -**

Another thing you could do is more the logic into the `Player` class. This is better as it keep the logic contained in one place so you can see what a `Player` can **DO** rather than having to search the whole program:

**New Player class:**

```
// The Player class
public class Player
{
    // Constructor
    public Player(int strength, int statPoints)
    {
        this.Strength = strength;
        this.StatPoints = statPoints;
    }

    // Method to gain strength if enough StatPoints
    public bool GainStrength()
    {        
        bool playerHasEnoughStatPoints = true;

        if (this.StatPoints < 1)
        {
            playerHasEnoughStatPoints = false;
        }
        else if (this.Strength < 8)
        {
            this.Strength++;
            this.StatPoints--;
        }

        return playerHasEnoughStatPoints;
    }

    // Property for StatPoints
    public int StatPoints { get; set; }

    // Property for Strength
    public int Strength { get; set; }
}
```

**New Form:**

```
// The Form or similar
public class MyFormOrSimilar
{   
    // When button pressed try and add strength to the player
    protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create new INSTANCE of the player and try to give them strength
        Player thePlayer = new Player(int.Parse(StrBox.Text), int.Parse(SPBox.Text));
        if (thePlayer.GainStrength())
        {
            StrBox.Text = thePlayer.Strength.ToString();
            SPBox.Text = thePlayer.StatPoints.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Earn more experience!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to give this a try now, but to be clear, there is no dummy object that can display the content of a variable for a winform, correct?

Comment: Plus the new class suggestion doesn't work because thePlayer is inaccessible from the player.cs. this.StatPoints seems to work however when used in the if statement.

Comment: Sorry @PaulWilliamFassett , I copied and pasted (as I said I don't have VS available right now so working by sight)! I have fixed the **Updated** section and changed it to be `this...` rather than `thePlayer...`. `this` gives you the instance of the class being used. having the method in the class is a much better approach as you can see what the class is capable of and allows you to make the change in one place.